# Allowing Firefox installed through Snap to associate links with non snap programs

Tags: firefox, snap, 18.04, ubuntu-core

I have just moved to Ubuntu 18.04 and am giving snaps a try, and so have set up Firefox as a snap package. Now I am trying to associate magnet links with my torrent client. I am however unable to let Firefox find and execute the torrent client, as it is installed globally.

Is there a interface extension I can connect (similar to removable-media) that would allow Firefox to launch the program?

Comment: Was unable to find a way to make this work, so gave up on using Firefox a snap.